All networking (wired & wireless) stopped working for no apparent reason [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS]
The networking stopped working on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system earlier for no apparent reason; both wifi and wired connections are affected.
I booted my laptop this morning, and was online with no issues, then locked my system for an hour or so; on my return it was apparent that it had spontaneously rebooted in my absence. No updates or software-modifying programs were running when I locked it, only Slack, Firefox and Chrome. After logging in again the Wifi symbol was showing the offline indicator, as though the network was unavailable, but it was (confirmed from other devices) and it also could not effectively use other networks, although on switching networks or disabling/enabling wifi it shows as "connected".
I have also disabled wifi and connected ethernet to my monitor and confirmed this is accessible via USB-C from my Macbook, but when I connect the affected laptop it says the Wired Networking is "connected" but the wired network icon has the same ? as the wifi icon.
I have an HP Elitebook x360 1030 G4 which has been running 22.04 LTS and more recently 24.04 LTS with no major issues to speak of. Last week I had to do a clean install of 22.04 LTS and apart from Bluetooth not working properly, had no major issues until today.
I've tried rebooting several times to no avail.
I've booted into the 22.04 LTS live environment from the USB boot media that I used to do the clean install from, and the networking works fine.
Output from the Ubuntu Forums wireless-info script is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bKP2292w2x/
